# SpriteKit Animation Physics

Tags: animation, sprite-kit

is there a way to apply skphysics to a animated character? Okay I have my player play an animation when I move it around the screen and below is it's animation code but for some reason when I want to apply physics to my animation, I get an error saying wrong data type. 
Sending 'SKSpriteNode *_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')

NO Reputation and I can't answer my own question so I posted here.

actually never mind I had to add this _Player.frame and I am hoping this is right and is putting physics on my character. However, please correct me if I am wrong. thanks.

```
- (void) Player {
_Player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bird"];
_Player.xScale = 0.88;
_Player.yScale = 0.88;
_Player.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[self addChild:_Player];
// 1
NSMutableArray *PlayerCh = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
// 2
for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    NSString *mytextureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bird%d", i];
    SKTexture *ItsTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:mytextureName];
    [PlayerCh  addObject:ItsTexture];
}
// 3
for (int i = 2; i > 1; i--) {
    NSString *mytextureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bird%d", i];
    SKTexture *ItsTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:mytextureName];
    [PlayerCh addObject:ItsTexture];
}
// 4
_PlayerAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:PlayerCh timePerFrame:0.1];
// SKPHYSICS FOR PLAYER

SKPhysicsBody *MYPLAYER = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:_Player];  // I get a error here.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Of course this program has to crash when it runs
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:_Player] expects a float not an SKPriteNode, what you probably want to do is change this line of code to the following:

```
SKPhysicsBody *MYPLAYER = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:_Player.size.width/2];
```

Comment: by the way friend thanks for your help but I already found the answer and answered my own question in the original post but since I don't have enough reputation I couldnt use the answer your question feature so please un-vote my question since this would affect my account. thanks.

Comment: I understand, BTW I am not the one who down voted it, and as a friendly gesture I will up vote it for you.

Comment: thanks. btw there is something I need help with with the game I am designing can I ask you please?

Comment: sure, go ahead, I will help if I can

Comment: thanks for your offer to help bud and here is the address for my post. can you also please take a look? thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876813/multiple-functions-in-touch-function-methods-sprite-kit

Comment: I have posted an answer to your other post, check it out